# Jibs fastening in a frame structure

Tags: steel, structures, cad, frame

I need to make a demountable frame for cycling trials:
[image]

I want to make it based on steel profile square tubes:
[image]

The design must have variable dimensions and slopes. I guess provide variable dimensions by using holes & bolted connections:
[image]

Side view:
[image]

The key difficulty is the creation of jibs to ensure structural rigidity. How to make jibs for a resizable design? Now I'm going to drill a lot of holes and when changing the size of the frame, rearrange the jibs in other holes. In this case, it is impossible to ensure an exact match of the holes.
What is the best way to attach the jibs to the main frame in this case? Can the hole be made larger than the bolt diameter, or can a hole be made in the shape of a slot at the end of the jibs? Is it possible to provide rigidity by tightening the bolt and nut tightly?... What other options are there for my case?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Threaded rod is usually the way to go for leveling feet. Threaded rod all the way would take too long to set up unless you had some creative release mechanism for the nut.  Pivots and slots, scissor lifts... Many different ways to tackle the adjustable height problem.

Comment: @Abel, thanks, now I guess to use slots & telescopic jibs instead of the many holes. Be note that long threaded rods strongly bend.

Comment: T slots and clamps could work - especially if the contacting surfaces are serrated.